# CDI: How to broadcast events between Dependent beans?

Tags: java, events, jakarta-ee, cdi

I created some instance of same classes with:

```
private Instance<MyObserver> myObserverFactory;

public MyObserver getNewInstance() {
  return myObserverFactory.get();
}
```

And my class:

```
// Dependent bean
public class MyObserver{
   public void observe(@Observes MyEvent myEvent) { /* do something */ }
}
```

Instead of having "manager bean" which keeps all *MyObserver* instances, I would like to communicate with them with events.
But with **Dependant** scope, events are sent every time to a new instance of *MyObserver*... And with Dependant scope, I can't use:

```
@Observes(notifyObserver = Reception.IF_EXISTS)
```

So my question is: **How to broadcast events between existing Dependant scoped beans?**
What scope can I use?

Thanks,

-Dush

Comment: I don't think that's possible because to satisfy that requirement CDI has to keep track of all instances (and they may be thousands) in order to call their observer. I recommend you should rethink your code design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Adrian Mitev is right: it's not possible to do that I as would like.

I'm using [Guava Event Bus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) for this purpose (be able to ping existing instance of beans). And I'm routing CDI event to it with this class:

```
/**
 * Configure Guava Event Bus to get CDI event and broadcast them to it.
 */
@ApplicationScoped
public class GuavaEventBus {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GuavaEventBus.class);

  private static final EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();

  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  private EventBus createGuavaEventBus() {
      return eventBus;
  }

  public void broadcastEveryEvent(@Observes Object event) {
      // There are a lot of bradcasted events, it may be a good solution to filter them.
      LOGGER.debug("Broadcast event: {}", event);
      eventBus.post(event);
  }

  /** Why not registring and unregistring by CDI event? ;) */ 
  public static void register(Object bean) {
      LOGGER.debug("Register bean: {}", bean);
      eventBus.register(bean);
  }

  public static void unregister(Object bean) {
      eventBus.unregister(bean);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, one recourse is to make your observer method static, but that is probably pretty limiting if you expected to ping each bean during the event.